# Storing Confidential Information in a Web-Accessible Directory?

Tags: php, file, security, curl

The answer to this question may be fairly obvious but I would like an explanation as to why one method of file security is preferential to the other.

Consider the following environment:

User uploads a file. The file gets renamed to: newfile_randomstring.png. The file is then sent to a remote server via cURL. When the remote server receives the file, a new directory is created and the file is stored as such:

'public_html/uploads/user_id/file_id/newfile_randomstring/newfile_randomstring.png'

Let's say these are important documents such as tax returns or legal documents.

My question is: Would uploading the files to a non web-accessible directory provide more security than the proposed environment? Secondly, does the proposed method of creating directory/file names from random strings using PHP's uniqid function provide adequate protection from unwanted access in the first place? (E.g. Someone figures out the IP address of the remote server and starts digging around trying to guess directory names and structures).

What if the files were automatically deleted soon after they are uploaded? Would it still be possible for bots/webscrapers to access the files?

Comment: some light reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity  "Storing Confidential Information in a Web-Accessible Directory?" is well bat-shit crazy.

Comment: simply put the files outside the web root, i can't conceive of why you wouldent do that.

Comment: PHP's [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is not meant to be securely random. It is meant to (hopefully) output a string that is different from the strings it has returned every other time it was called, but it is ***not*** meant to output strings that are hard to guess, and it is ***not*** much better/different than an incrementing integer.

Comment: classic XY problem here, go back and ask the question you think this crazyness would solve.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, store them in a non-web accessible directory immediately. If sensible doc is published in the web, is easily to obtain and use it for ex torsion and fraud. Get it out of the public folder, then any hacker will have to break into your system first to attain the info.

No, random string is no protection at all, that's why permissions exists.

Yes, they're still available, for a lesser amount of time but still available.

Chances are nothing happens, if you just think of web scrappers try to get into the site, but most hacking is made through social engineering, and the system you describe is everything but secure, there are a lot of back doors open.

Answer (score -1):

> Would uploading the files to a non web-accessible directory provide more security than my current environment?

Short answer: yes, the less access given the better. However, I wouldn't say your system is secure just because the files reside in a non web-accessible directory. I do have questions about what you are currently doing but I will get to those below.

> Secondly, does my current method of creating directory/file names from random strings using PHP's uniqid function provide adequate protection from unwanted access in the first place? (E.g. Someone figures out the IP address of my remote server and starts digging around trying to guess directory names and structures)

No, obscuring file names in itself is not sufficiently secure to stop an attacker from getting access to the files. You should, at the very least, keep these files on a private network that doesn't have direct public access, require (strong) authentication to access the files, have an authorization policy on which users can access which files, only connect over secure channels (e.g., TLS), encrypt the files (preferably require the client to decrypt the file with a key that they are to have received during account creation but that may or may not be possible given your use cases), and log/monitor all the events (e.g., authentication, file download, failed authentication, etc.).

> What if the files were automatically deleted soon after they are uploaded? Would it still be possible for bots/webscrapers to access the files?

Deleting after you don't need it is a good idea but won't provide you sufficient security on its own. The amount of time that bots/scrapers have to access the files is certainly minimized but it is still possible for them to access the files. You definitely want to get these sensitive files out of the public directory.

My questions for you:

1. Is the final resting place of these files (i.e., the directory that you upload them to via cURL) publicly accessible? Is it possible for me to access that server if I know the URL and port?
2. Are you sending everything over a secure channel (e.g., TLS)?
3. Do your servers require authentication? If so, how do you authenticate?
4. Are there different access policies put in place for different files?
5. How do you deal with collisions (i.e., file to be uploaded has the same name as another file on disk)? Do you just assume that there won't be any because you are using a random string?
6. Why is the server that is sending the file naming the file? This can lead to a variety of attacks that you don't want to deal with.
7. Do you do any input sanitation on the file (and its metadata) to be uploaded? At the very least, do you make sure it doesn't exceed a certain size limit?
8. Who is to use these files after they have been uploaded and how will they be accessed?
9. Where do you keep track of the randomly generated name and what it maps to?
10. What are the permissions settings on all the directories that the file contents get uploaded to?

I am sure I will have more questions once these are answered.

**EDIT: Added another question**

Comment: 1.) Yes; 2.) No 3.) Yes; RSA key authentication; 4.) Users will not be able to access remote server directly. Only pages they visit on the originating server can request a file to be sent from the remote server to the originating server.  5.) Each user and each upload have a unique ID based on their unique primary key in MySQL DB. 6.) I have to upload multiple files at once; not sure of any way around this. 7.) Yes, file size and file type by checking the MIME type. 8.) Users who have registered on the site only. 9.) Filenames are stored in a  MySQL table along with user ID and file ID.

Comment: 10.) On the file with the receiving cURL operation: 775. Files and subdirectories are 755.